# Salesforce Describe Call on Sharing object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Anyone has any idea on how to fetch sharing objects or sharing rules from describe call? I think its not feasible!

Thanks for you help,

Best,
Manju

Comment: please share your code , and what have you tried so far , and welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

The describe information is at the object and field level, whereas sharing rules are at the record level. So describe info won't tell you who can access a particular record.

The **UserRecordAccess** object can be queried to determine if a user has access to a single record or a group of records. (Note that you can query many records at the same time by using an IN clause with a list of recordids.)

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm

Answer (score 0):

**You can describe sObjects that hold sharing** associated to particular records, but why would you need to? It's not like we can add any fields to them. To query them maybe? Works in REST API (`/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/AccountShare`) as well as in Metadata API.

**You can describe sharing rules** (I think it's a feature introduced in 2012). To do that check which metadata your Eclipse is retrieving, package.xml should contain entries similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AccountCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AccountOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CampaignCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CampaignOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CaseCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CaseOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContactCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ContactOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LeadOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OpportunityCriteriaBasedSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OpportunityOwnerSharingRule</name>
    </types>
    <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

And finally **you can query the objects** from (1) or - as mentioned by Bob - the `UserRecordAccess` table if you want to know about access to particular records.